# How to unlimit the number of simultaneous connections on windows?

Tags: windows, sql-server

How can I make microsoft windows to accept more then 20 connections, I have a microsoft sql server express that seems to be dropping connections after 20 connections.

Any sugestions?

Windows 2008 server but a guy says that the system maybe limited to 20 connections because of a "patch" that was used for windows 7;

Comment: You upgrade the version of Windows you are using.  It is difficult to answer without the specific version you are using.

Comment: Windows 2008 server but a guy says that the system maybe limited to 20 connections because of a "patch" that was used for windows 7;

Comment: What patch exactly?

Comment: If the clients are ASP.NET, or programs on workstations, do you know if they are they using connection pooling or grabbing a connection and keeping it open for the life of the program? The latter would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

The number of allowed connections [is due to the OS, not to SQL Server Express](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31173/max-connections-sql-server-express-could-have). Applying a patch intended for Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008 *might* have this bad side effect, if it somehow convinces SSE that it is actually running on Windows 7.

I would reinstall SQL Server. That should be a sufficiently large clue to it that it is now running on Windows Server.